# Почему создается файл не там где указываю?

Tags: php

Собственно делаю лог файл, у меня проект вот так состоит:

```
/
├── Class
├── Includes
├── Logs
└── Public
```

Содержимое `Public/index.php`:

```
$logger= new \Modules\Logger("../Logs/log.txt");
$logger->logAction("Login","Admin");
```

Но он упорно мне создает файл именно в `Public`. В чем может быть причина?

Класс `Logger` в папке `Class/Modules`:

```
namespace Modules;

use SplFileInfo;

class Logger extends SplFileInfo
{
    public function logAction($action,$user)
    {
        try{
        $dt=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",time());
        $message="$user:| $action -|$dt\n";
        file_put_contents($this->getFilename(), $message, FILE_APPEND);
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            echo "File error";
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61639/discussion-on-question-by-firesoul-------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `SplFileInfo::getFileName` возвращает только имя файла, без пути к нему. Попробуйте использовать `SplFileInfo::getRealPath`.